# ios static library issue (skip sbjson library code from static library of ios)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

I am creating a static library in ios. which uses sbjson parser 3rd party library and things are working fine. if we only use ABC.a library in any other project.

The the problem arises when we include DEF.a libary of any other project which internally uses Sbjson parser.

So, my query is that how can we skip building 3rd party libray like sbjson, afnetworking etc. with my ABC.a library.

Any help will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for the problem

below url mite help all

http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/excluding-files-from-production-xcode-builds/